# python tkinter canvas size using scrollbar

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

Edited: I want the size of `canvas1` to be adjusted using `scrollbar`. When I run this, only `canvas1` is visible no place left on frame for `canvas2`. I want `canvas1`'s size on the frame to be somewhere near 300*400 and when I scroll it to visualize the whole frame (1000*800)

I want to construct a frame with two canvas. but the problem is that i dont know how to fit first canvas within the scrollbar. In the following code the size of canvas is huge because of that the second canvas is not displayed in the frame. What i want is to fix the size of first canvas within the scrollbar. Am new to tkinter so have no idea how to do that
i will really appreciate your help

```
root=Tk()

master=Frame(root,width=300,height=300)
master.grid(row=0,column=0)

xscrollbar = Scrollbar(master, orient=HORIZONTAL)
xscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)
yscrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)

canvas1=Canvas(master, width=1000, height=800, background='white',xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set,yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
canvas1.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
xscrollbar.config(command=canvas1.xview)
yscrollbar.config(command=canvas1.yview)

canvas2=Canvas(master, width=100, height=200, background='pink',xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set,yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
canvas2.grid(row=2,column=0)

mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand "fix the size of the canvas within the scrollbar" (particularly the "within the scrollbar" -- the canvas isn't "in" the scrollbar). The code seems to be doing exactly what you want -- you get a 1000x800 canvas and a 100x200 canvas. I also don't know what you mean by the second one not being displayed; I see both the pink and the white canvas. Can you try to reword your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is set the canvas *size* to be 300x400, and then set the *scrollregion* attribute of the canvas to be 1000*800.

```
canvas1 = Canvas(..., width=300, height=400, scrollregion=(0,0,1000,800))
```